# chrome extension background page debug

Tags: google-chrome-extension

You can see access the background page's console by clicking the link to the background console in `chrome://extensions`
Is there a way to look at the html page itself?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? you have free access to any view of extension in development mode

Comment: I don't think you can display the background page in a visible tab.

Comment: You can see the live updates of your background through console. However, I haven't found a way to see the live updates on a webpage instead. The reason I need this is that my background page consists of an iframe and you cannot access the iframe from a console.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to look at the background.html? For example for mac OS, Google Chrome installs the extension into a randomly generated directory in

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`

and registers it in its Preferences file. You may find the background.html there. And You can view Chrome extension folder placed in the following directory in Windows as well

```
C:\Documents and Settings\*UserName*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not address my question. If you were to do this, you can just go to `chrome-extension//extension_id/path_to_background.html`. But that's not the background page that is updated while the extension is running.

Comment: Could you describe more why you can't see the live updates on a webpage by Chrome DevTools and also I'm afraid you should update your issue to make it not so confused to be clear.